# How to play lot of SoundPool files and a radio online in the same time

Tags: java, android, soundpool

I just created a app in Android Studio for two reasons:

1. Make an instrumental-sampler, each pad will play a sound thanks to SoundPool.
2. And playing a radio online (using a service to play in the background).

The radio works fine and the sampler works also, but I can't use a different sampler (I have 3 different ones, with 6 pads in each one) without any errors such as:

> AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client; transfer 4, track 44100 Hz,
>   output 48000 Hz

and when I use lot of sound:

```
AudioTrack: AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12
SoundPool: Error creating AudioTrack
```

This is my first problem, and after that the sound is playing when I touch the button maybe 1/10.

My second problem is when this problem occurs, the radio can't work anymore with this message appearing in logcat:

```
AudioTrack: AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12        
AudioTrack-JNI: Error -12 initializing AudioTrack          
android.media.AudioTrack: Error code -20 when initializing AudioTrack.        
ExoPlayerImplInternal: Playback error.
```

When I just use 1 sampler, or just the radio, it's OK. I just got this message in the sampler:

```
AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client; transfer 4, track 44100 Hz, output 48000 Hz
```

...but if I use different samplers or playing fast a lot of sound, or with the radio, it's not working

I think using a thread is OK; I don't know how it's exactly works, but in lot of posts SoundPool with a thread isn't working.

I tried to change my .mp3 files to .ogg or change the track Hz, but it's not working.

I still have these permissions in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

My Sampler's files are like this:

```
public class ActivityDrumsLofi extends AppCompatActivity {

    SoundPool Soundpool;

    private int sound_g, sound_h, sound_i, sound_j, sound_k, sound_l;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Soundpool = new SoundPool(32, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

        sound_g= Soundpool.load(this, R.raw.kick6lofi, 1);
        sound_h= Soundpool.load(this, R.raw.kicklofi, 1);
        sound_i= Soundpool.load(this, R.raw.hatlofi, 1);
        sound_j= Soundpool.load(this, R.raw.hithatlofi, 1);
        sound_k= Soundpool.load(this, R.raw.tambilofi, 1);
        sound_l= Soundpool.load(this, R.raw.snare2lofi, 1);
    }

    public  void playsample1 (View view) {
            SoundpoolLofi.play(sound_g, 1, 1, 1,0, 1);
    }

    public  void playsample2 (View view) {
        SoundpoolLofi.play(sound_i, 1, 1, 1,0, 1);
    }

    public  void playsnare (View view) {
        SoundpoolLofi.play(sound_k, 1, 1, 1,0, 1);
    }

    public  void playkick (View view) {
        SoundpoolLofi.play(sound_h, 1, 1, 1,0, 1);
    }

    public  void playhat (View view) {
        SoundpoolLofi.play(sound_j, 1, 1, 1,0, 1);
    }

    public  void platclap (View view) {
        SoundpoolLofi.play(sound_l, 1, 1, 1,0, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry in advance for a short answer. I would comment, but I can't because I'm new to SO :)

Status -12 says, that you are basically running out of memory. This means, that either your sound-files are too big or the more likely case: you are exceeding the limit of simultaneously loaded sounds.
Soundpool can only "hold" 32 sound objects. Problem is, that every time you play a sound, it adds one to that. You have to Soundpool.release() at some point to clear up the memory.
Second problem is, that you can't find out, when Soundpool has finished playing your sound, to know when you could release it. Since you're using it over and over in the same Activity etc. it's probably not gonna work to release in onPause() or something.
A "hacky" solution would be, that you release it after a specified amount of time through a handler for example, because you know, how long your sounds are. That's definitely not an elegant solution, so maybe someone else has a better one.

I hope this helps a little (my first answer :P )